# Custom Diaglog box android

Tags: android

i am trying to make a custom dialog box with 2 spinners and 2 buttons.
i am doing the following coding

this is xml for custom GUI inside dialog box

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SORT BY" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:prompt="@string/prompt1"
    android:entries="@array/ordersortby"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ORDER"
    />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:prompt="@string/address"
     android:entries="@array/ordersortby1"


    />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cancel"
     />
```

in strings i am declaring following

```
 <string name="prompt1">Order Number</string>

 <string-array name="ordersortby">
    <item>Order Number</item>
    <item>Date Submitted</item>
    <item>Date Entered</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="ordersortby1">
    <item>ASC</item>
    <item>DESC</item>
</string-array>
```

and in activity i am doing following

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(orders.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.orderpicker);
            dialog.setTitle("Sort By Dialog");
            dialog.show();
```

when running this , i am getting this
[spinner](https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/attachment/?ui=2&ik=9d0a355143&view=att&th=13be14a55d1648b1&attid=0.1&disp=inline&realattid=f_hb98u8an0&safe=1&zw&saduie=AG9B_P_64Zt8tmpfB8IaP-OlWK0m&sadet=1356694476836&sads=kwbji4tR99LBA9utUKFRug25_c8&sadssc=1)

my problem is why i am not getting any data inside these pickers. please help me.

Comment: Please see my answer, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let use below code,

```
 spinner_ordersortby = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_ordersortby);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.ordersortby, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_language.setAdapter(adapter);
```

another thing is make sure your array should inside this directory

```
/res/values/arrays.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code before `dialog.show();` and define your string array into string.xml file, it will solve your problem.

```
Spinner mSpinner1 = (Spinner)dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner_ordersortby);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.string.ordersortby, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
mSpinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: this is not the problem. have you seen my picture? i when i am clicking on the spinner then the spinner with data is coming but when i am choosing the data from it , it is not showing in the spinner. let me create an image to show you.

Comment: https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/attachment/?ui=2&ik=9d0a355143&view=att&th=13be1b0206142c48&attid=0.1&disp=inline&realattid=f_hb9ct8vp0&safe=1&zw&saduie=AG9B_P_64Zt8tmpfB8IaP-OlWK0m&sadet=1356701146007&sads=mmPZweirDM2AbBP2qZXAXRb5WaQ

Comment: plz see the image i just posted.

Comment: @SachinKadian Image you are posted is not showing and if possible send me your demo application, after changes i will send you back.

Answer (score 0):

in your code try something like this

```
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View myview = factory.inflate(R.layout.orderpicker, null); 
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(orders.this);
        dialog.setContentView(myview);
        dialog.setTitle("Sort By Dialog");
        dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the view.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);
```

Now use this `view` to declare your spinner.

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

This will solve your problem.